# How to Define Variable in jquery from PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am able to pass the server name to PHP which runs the query successfully.  In the html file I want the rating option to change depending on what value was returned from the PHP file.  In my file I set it to D but I need to change that to relflect what is being returned from PHP.

server.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var id = $('#existingserver').val();            
            $('#assetCenter').click(function(){
                var id = $('#textfield').val();
                $.get('servertest.php',{q:id}, function(htmlData){
                    $('#txtHint').html(htmlData);
                    var rating = $(htmlData).find("td[data-col=rating]").text();
                    alert(rating);
                    });
            });
        });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label>Existing Server</label><input type="text" name="existingserver" id="textfield" maxlength="15"/>

            <input type="checkbox" id="assetCenter" >Select to Pull Asset Center Data<br>
            <br />
            <br />
            Rating
            <select name="rating" id="rating" >
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
                <option value="D">D</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <br />

        <div id="txtHint"><b>Server info will be listed here.</b></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

servertest.php

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'assignip', 'assignip');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ipreservation", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM acdata WHERE servername = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Servername</th>
<th>Contact</th>
<th>Classification</th>
<th>Rating</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['servername'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['contact'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['classification'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['rating'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<td data-col='rating'>" . $row['rating'] . "</td>";
  }

  echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

database fields: servername, contact, classification, rating
Data: Server1, Ray, Production, A

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I need to change this line - $('#rating').val('D'); - to what is being returned from PHP.  In my example server1 has the rating set to A so I need the rating variable set to A so the rating option will be set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP code, change the output so it displays the value you want to show, without any html tags.

Next in your html code, change your $(document).ready callback so that 'D' is replaced with the response text of the call (that is what PHP will return).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just starting using jquery a few days ago.  Can you please provide more info on how I need to change $(document).ready?

Comment: No problem... first I want to check something.  In your $(document).ready, your htmlData is what you are outputting from PHP?  Also, what you want for 'D' is embedded in this output, or is it a separate source that you want to add?

Comment: It is embedded in the output from PHP which gets it from the db.

Comment: In that case, you have to search through your output.  Did you try @dbaseman's answer below?

Comment: I am able to get the correct value now so I am very close. I just need the option to change the rating in the html section. I added: var rating = $(htmlData).find("td[data-col=rating]").text(); alert(rating); and the alert is showing the correct value. I basically need to refresh the HTML code for the rating so it changes to that value.

Comment: Would you update your post to show your current code and what's left?  It still shows you using $("#rating").val('D')...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to use a JQuery selector to get the rating:

```
// get the text of the 4th td
var rating = $(htmlData).find("td").eq(3).text();

$("#rating").val(rating);
```

---

However, you might notice this approach is kind of brittle (aka tightly coupled) -- if something changes in the UI, say you re-order the columns, then the above logic will break.

I'd suggest returning the data from the server as JSON, and then applying a client-side template to get the HTML table.  At the very least, give the columns a name like this:

```
echo "<td data-col='rating'>" . $row['rating'] . "</td>";
```

And then you can select on the client side by referencing the name:

```
var rating = $(htmlData).find("td[data-col=rating]").text();
```

Comment: It is getting the value so I'm very close but I just need the rating option value in the HTML below to change.  I added: